# Emoji dictionary cant find modules ./emojis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, emoji

I'm currently trying to use [emoji-dictionary](https://github.com/IonicaBizau/emoji-dictionary) on my project but it fails to run!

I'm receive the `index.js:2 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "./emojis"`  error!

Comment: You need to show some code. How are you importing it ? how are you using it ?

Comment: Show the code of index.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the [reactjs](/questions/tagged/reactjs) tag appears, I speculate you use Webpack and you didn't set up the `json-loader`. `emojis.json` is a file from the `emojilib` package which is a dependency of `emoji-dictionary`.

Install `json-loader`:

```
npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

And then configure it:

```
module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Check out [`json-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/json-loader) on GitHub for more information.

If this is not solving the issue, you may need to explain a little bit the context. It seems to not be related to the package itself because •it's working on my machine•.

Comment: Thanks Ionica! I had already setup the json-loader but to solve it I also had to add

resolve: {
  extensions: ['.json']
}

Now it is working! Thanks! :)